# Why an @ManyToMany should caused a NullPointerException?

Tags: java-8, jpa-2.1, hibernate-5.x

I know that it could be too much vague but what could cause a NullPointerException after adding a @ManyToMany in my jpa entities?

All code is the same, I deleted only the entity linked to the croos table and modified the two entities that before were linked to that entity adding @ManyToMany so the problem isn't the external code or in the db.

The two entities are also linked with a @OneToMany with a second field. Could be this the problem?

This is a structure of my database:

- table1: id, name, description and table2_id;
- table2: id, name and description;
- cross_table: id, table1_id, table2_id and timestamp

Could be a problem the two Set into the entity Table2?

My specs are:

- java8
- hibernate5.2
- jpa2.1

Comment: Jpa doesn't throw any `NullPointerException`, if no elements existed in db jpa will create an empty `Set` for you, maybe you operates on a transient entity and not initializing the `Set`.

Comment: @holi-java can you tell me something more? I changed the fetchType from LAZY to EAGER but nothing changed ...

Comment: This is the NPE that you don't quote, or give stack trace for. Consequently there is nothing anyone can say.

Comment: @Neil Stockton  You are right, unfortunally the stackTrace wasn't helpful and I would be generic because, as I wrote on my answer, I was sure that the problem was not the annotation and writing too much it could be confuse!

Answer (score 0):

As usual, for me, the message caused a misterunderstanding, I thought the problem was @ManyToMany instead the problem was a my error in hibernate.cfg because I removed only the entity table1_table2 and not the mapping annotation on hibernate.cfg!
Thank you @holi-java for your hint!